# Android - Display WebView in Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am developing an android application in which i wish to open the phone's default browser with in the application. while exiting from the browser, the application should resume to its current state. Please help me with the Sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as below by using `loadUrl`:

```
WebView myWebView=null;
myWebView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.<WebviewID>);
myWebView.loadUrl(<URL to be loaded>);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to use `webview`. in between you pass your `url` in `webview`and `webview`display properly any webpage.put your webview in layout and past code like this ::

```
                    WebView wv_introduction;
                wv_introduction = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ady_solwv);
        wv_introduction.loadUrl(str_url);
```

For more information :: [**click here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
//add webview programmatically 

//your linear layout 

childHolder.addView(showWebView());


private WebView showWebView() {
        WebView webView =new WebView(context);
        webView.loadUrl("http://yourUrl.com");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        return webView;
}
```